# Keep column names with mutate_at and lst() instead of funs()

Tags: r, dplyr

In dplyr 0.8.0, `funs()` is deprecated, and the new format is to use `list()` with `~`. However, I have noticed that this no longer updates columns using `mutate_at()` as previously expected.

```
> set.seed(5)
> testdf <- data.frame(a = sample(1:9, size = 5, replace = TRUE),
+                      b = 1:5,
+                      c = LETTERS[1:5])
> testdf
  a b c
1 2 1 A
2 7 2 B
3 9 3 C
4 3 4 D
5 1 5 E
```

Example of old code:

```
> testdf %>% mutate_at(.vars = c('a','b'), .funs = funs(. + 2))
   a b c
1  4 3 A
2  9 4 B
3 11 5 C
4  5 6 D
5  3 7 E
```

Example of new code:

```
> testdf %>% mutate_at(.vars = c('a','b'), .funs = lst(~. + 2))
  a b c a_~. + 2 b_~. + 2
1 2 1 A        4        3
2 7 2 B        9        4
3 9 3 C       11        5
4 3 4 D        5        6
5 1 5 E        3        7
```

EDIT: I just noticed that if I use `list()` this problem is resolved:

```
> testdf %>% mutate_at(.vars = c('a','b'), .funs = list(~. + 2))
   a b c
1  4 3 A
2  9 4 B
3 11 5 C
4  5 6 D
5  3 7 E
```

However, I wish to use `lst()` because within my code I regularly requiring unquoting variables using `!!!`, which is not supported by `list()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396890/unquote-a-list-of-functions-inside-r-dplyr-functions/))

I'm not sure of the proper way to use `lst()` while retaining the names.

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898288/786542?

Comment: @Tung can you please see my edit? Unfortunately `list()` doesn't support unqouting. .

Comment: Have you tried `rlang::list2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rlang::list2`

> is equivalent to list(...) but provides tidy dots semantics:

```
>  testdf %>% mutate_at(.vars = c('a','b'), .funs = rlang::list2(~. + 2))
   a b c
1  4 3 A
2  9 4 B
3 11 5 C
4  5 6 D
5  3 7 E
```